# Can't upload file to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'am trying to upload files to firebase in react, But the file upload progress reaches 100% then suddenly it shows me an unknown error like

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request. Could not create object",
    "status": "CREATE_OBJECT"
  }
}
```

this is the code I'm using to upload the file, This is the actual component where file uploading is done, The user opens a modal to select a file and then after selecting and pressing send in the modal the file uploading starts in the below component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Segment, Button, Input, ButtonGroup } from "semantic-ui-react";
import firebase from "../../firebase";
import FileModal from "./FileModal";
import uuidv4 from "uuid/v4";

class MessageForm extends Component {
  state = {
    storageRef: firebase.storage().ref(),
    message: "",
    channel: this.props.currentChannel,
    user: this.props.currentUser,
    loading: false,
    errors: [],
    modal: false,
    uploadState: "",
    uploadTask: null,
    percentUploaded: 0
  };

  uploadFile = (file, metadata) => {
    const pathToUpload = this.state.channel.id;
    const ref = this.props.messagesRef;
    const filePath = `chat/public/${uuidv4}.jpg`;

    this.setState(
      {
        uploadState: "uploading",
        uploadTask: this.state.storageRef.child(filePath).put(file, metadata)
      },
      () => {
        this.state.uploadTask.on(
          "state_changed",
          snap => {
            const percentUploaded = Math.round(
              (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100
            );
            this.setState({ percentUploaded });
          },
          err => {
            console.error(err);
            this.setState({
              errors: [...this.state.errors, err],
              uploadState: "error",
              uploadTask: null
            });
          },
          () => {
            console.log(this.state.uploadTask);
            this.state.uploadTask.snapshot.ref
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then(downloadUrl => {
                this.sendFileMessage(downloadUrl, ref, pathToUpload);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                this.setState({
                  errors: [...this.state.errors, err],
                  uploadState: "error",
                  uploadTask: null
                });
              });
          }
        );
      }
    );
  };

  sendFileMessage = (fileUrl, ref, pathToUpload) => {
    ref
      .child(pathToUpload)
      .push()
      .set(this.createMessage(fileUrl))
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          uploadState: "done"
        }).catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
          this.setState({
            errors: [...this.state.errors, err]
          });
        });
      });
  };

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: true
    });
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: false
    });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  createMessage = (fileUrl = null) => {
    const message = {
      timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      user: {
        id: this.state.user.uid,
        name: this.state.user.displayName,
        avatar: this.state.user.photoURL
      }
    };
    if (fileUrl != null) {
      message["image"] = fileUrl;
    } else {
      message["content"] = this.state.message.trim();
    }

    return message;
  };

  sendMessage = () => {
    const { messagesRef } = this.props;
    const { message, channel } = this.state;

    if (message) {
      this.setState({
        loading: true
      });
      messagesRef
        .child(channel.id)
        .push()
        .set(this.createMessage())
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            message: "",
            errors: []
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            errors: [...this.state.errors, err]
          });
        });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        errors: [...this.state.errors, { message: "Add a message" }]
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { errors, message, loading, modal } = this.state;
    return (
      <Segment className="message__form">
        <Input
          fluid
          name="message"
          style={{ marginBottom: "0.7em" }}
          icon="add"
          iconPosition="left"
          placeholder="Write your message"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          className={
            errors.some(error => error.message.includes("message"))
              ? "error"
              : ""
          }
          value={message}
        />
        <ButtonGroup icon widths="2">
          <Button
            onClick={this.sendMessage}
            disabled={loading}
            color="orange"
            content="Add reply"
            labelPosition="left"
            icon="edit"
          />
          <Button
            color="violet"
            content="Upload Media"
            labelPosition="right"
            icon="cloud upload"
            onClick={this.openModal}
          />
          <FileModal
            modal={modal}
            closeModal={this.closeModal}
            uploadFile={this.uploadFile}
          />
        </ButtonGroup>
      </Segment>
    );
  }
}

export default MessageForm;
```

Comment: If you'd like help resolving this you'll need to share more details, likely including the code you're using to upload the file and steps you've taken to diagnose or resolve it already.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I suspect that your error might be related to the way you are storing the `uploadTask` in the component's `state`... and it makes me pretty uncomfortable - it seems to violate one of the core principles of using component state in React.

As you've probably heard already **state should only be mutated via the `setState` command**... and the problem with your approach is that the `uploadTask` portion of the state **will be mutated during the upload execution**. In fact, your code counts on it - you've written it so that as the `uploadTask` is updated, its percentage gets displayed on screen.

Overall, you've got the right idea - just take that `uploadTask: this.state.storageRef.child(filePath).put(file, metadata)` assignment out of your `state`... something like this:

```
uploadFile = (file, metadata) => {
    const pathToUpload = this.state.channel.id;
    const ref = this.props.messagesRef;
    const filePath = `chat/public/${uuidv4}.jpg`;

    this.setState(
        {
            uploadState: "uploading",
        },
        () => {
            let uploadTask = this.state.storageRef.child(filePath).put(file, metadata);
            uploadTask.on(
                "state_changed",
                snap => {
                    const percentUploaded = Math.round(
                        (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100
                    );
                    this.setState({ percentUploaded });
                },
                err => {
                    console.error(err);
                    this.setState({
                        errors: [...errors, err],
                        uploadState: "error",
                    });
                },
                () => {
                    console.log(uploadTask);
                    uploadTask.snapshot.ref
                        .getDownloadURL()
                        .then(downloadUrl => {
                            this.sendFileMessage(downloadUrl, ref, pathToUpload);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.error(err);
                            this.setState({
                                errors: [...this.state.errors, err],
                                uploadState: "error",
                            });
                        });
                }
            );
        }
    );
};
```

(*Untested code, conceptual only*)